# Regex for getting specific groups

Tags: php, regex

I need a regex syntax for getting specific groups in a string that are delimited with the '%' charavter. I have this string as example:

%David davidson%Hello I can store 1000 numbers too%anotherchain%how are you!?%

I want to store in different PHP variables those matches like this

```
$var1 = david davidson;
$var2 = Hello I can store numbers;
```

... etc

but I don't know how to get a specific group of characters (per example get the second match that doesn't start with a symbol or with a % symbol)

I tried with this code `%.*?(%)` but it only returns the first and the third match but I actually want to select specific groups

I searched it on google and here but I didn't found an answer that fits a little with what I need, probably because I don't know the keywords I need to search to get a good answer

Comment: If the separator is always `%`, you could use `$vars = explode('%', $string);`

Comment: Carlos beat me with his reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
preg_match_all('/[^%]+/sim', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
print_r($result);
```

This will give you:

- David davidson
- Hello I can store 1000 numbers too
- anotherchain
- how are you!?

  [^%]+

This means in regex, every char except "%"

Comment: Seems like a `preg_split` variant might make more sense here.

Comment: Why not just `str_replace('%', '', $string);`?

Comment: preg_match_all is better cause he want to get groups as in one array. but preg_split is also useusable

Comment: @user1477388 He want to get some part of a string not a change value. He can use explode("%",$array); but this will give two empty key (for start end %).

Comment: Wow!! what Brend posted works like a charm! Many many many thanks for this one! I spent more than 2 hours figuring how to get that